# Styling <select> tag when option has been selected [CSS3]

Tags: html, css, select, styling, materialize

I have a select tag, like so:

```
<select>
  <option>Blah</option>
  <option>Blah</option>
  <option>Blah</option>
  <option>Blah</option>
</select>
```

I am using MaterializeCSS as my CSS framework, and have successfully overridden and applied selective styling to other input elements like textareas, etc. (http://materializecss.com/forms.html)

I just want to adjust the `border-bottom`, and the `color` of the  tag after an option has been selected.

I've tried the following pseudo-classes: `[:active, :focus, :checked, :enabled, :valid, ::before, and ::after]` trying to find the proper state for me to apply the CSS rules. As always, I've dug through the materialize source code and trawled MDN for the proper answer, but no such luck so far.

I'd love someone to point me to the proper documentation, or throw me a bone on this one. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't possible using CSS. Some possible workarounds:

1. Use javascript
2. Use the html5 required attribute along with CSS's `:required` pseudo class. Something like:

---

```
<select required>
    <option value="">None</option>
    <option>Blah</option>
    <option>Blah</option>
    <option>Blah</option>
    <option>Blah</option>
</select>
```

---

```
select {
    border: 5px solid #ccc;
}

select:valid {
    border-color: green;
}
```

Not a perfect solution but it might help with what you are doing.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s1zj2awL/)

[Browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I think I'll just write little bit of JS to accomplish this. Would you happen to know if there are any plans to allow for this sort of thing in the future HTML/CSS specs?

Comment: I haven't heard of anything similar and I don't think this is the sort of thing they would add but I could well be wrong.

Comment: @WillCarron btw don't forget to mark this as answered if it answered your question so that other users can see that it has been answered. To mark it as answered click the checkbox next to the up / down arrows.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me! Will remember in the future!